# Does React Hook - useState has delay time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

When i use isLoggedIn with useState to confirm loggedIn or not,
and pass it to -> Router -> Navigation.
It shows "TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null"

But, when not using isLoggedIn, it works.
i replaced it to boolean value.

Why this happening?

here is my code

In App.js

```
function App() {
  const [init, setInit] = useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userObj, setUserObj] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    authService.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        setUserObj({
          displayName: user.displayName,
          uid: user.uid,
          updateProfile: (args) => {
            return user.updateProfile(args);
          },
        });
      } else {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
        setUserObj(null);
      }
      setInit(true);
    });
  }, []);

    ...

  return (
<>
  {console.log('updated')}
  {init ? (
    <AppRouter
      refreshUser={refreshUser}
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      userObj={userObj}
    />
  ) : (
    'Initializing...'
  )}
</>
```

In Router.js

```
const AppRouter = ({refreshUser, isLoggedIn, userObj}) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      {isLoggedIn && <Navigation userObj={userObj}></Navigation>}
    </Router>
  );
};
```

In Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = ({ userObj }) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/profile">{userObj.displayName} Profile</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: what does your `console.log(user);` return to you?

Comment: Do you even really need the extra `isLoggedIn` state? In your snippet it appears to only gate the passing on of `userObj`. `userObj` is `null` when `isLoggedIn` is `false`, you could simply `{userObj && <Navigation userObj={userObj} />}`. I don't think this will resolve your apparent state synchronicity issue, but it reduces moving parts. There's no delay in time, per se, but react state updates *are* asynchronous.